# summarytools dfSummary markdown not printing variable labels

Tags: r, summarytools

I am trying to get my variable labels to print on my dfSummary Table in my markdown output. I can get the label column when I use the R console viewer (with print(method="viewer")), but when I knit the markdown the label column drops off.
See an example of my problem using the mtcars dataset

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(results = "asis")
library(Hmisc)
library(summarytools)
```

```
st_options(plain.ascii = FALSE,       
           style        = "rmarkdown", 
           footnote     = NA,          
           subtitle.emphasis = FALSE) 
label(mtcars$gear) ="Gears"
label(mtcars$cyl) ="Cylinders"
mt<-subset(mtcars, select=c(gear, cyl))
print(dfSummary(mt, labels.col=TRUE, display.labels=TRUE), method = "render", Variable.label=TRUE)
```

This is the resulting table in the markdown output

table in markdown

[image]

**BUT** this is what I want it to look like, with the Label column, which is what I get when I enter the code directly into RConsole:

```
print(dfSummary(mt, labels.col=TRUE, display.labels=TRUE), method = "viewer", Variable.label=TRUE)
```

table using R viewer

[image]
I'd like to get the "Label" column on the rmarkdown table - can anyone help with this issue?

Comment: I don't get the `Label` column in the Viewer. Output is the same while knitting as well as in Viewer.

Answer (score 0):

The labels are lost when you use subset. Just apply the labels *after* subsetting.

Also, since *summarytools* has its own `label()` function, you don't need to load *Hmisc* for that.

Here's how I got it to display optimally:

````
---
title: "Labels in dfSummary"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(results = "asis")
library(summarytools)
st_options(plain.ascii     = FALSE,       
           dfSummary.style = "grid",
           dfSummary.graph.magnif = .75,
           footnote        = NA) 

```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
st_css()
```

```{r}
mt <- subset(mtcars, select=c(gear, cyl))
label(mt$gear) ="Gears"
label(mt$cyl) ="Cylinders"
print(dfSummary(mt), method = "render")
```
````

[image: rendered results]